# Parsing multiple nested elements as an unordered list with SimpleXML using PHP foreach

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I'm working with an XML product list that displays a list of around 20 products, and within each `<item>` there is a `<description>` and then one `<bullet>` for each. Here's an example:

[XML File with `<bullet>` List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZNAM.png)

I'm using a `foreach` loop with SimpleXML to pull in the product data, and all individual tags such as `<image>` and `<title>` are working fine.

My issue is that it is only parsing the first `<bullet>` for each product and not all of them. To fix this I attempted to add a `for` loop which targets all nested items within the `<description>` tag and outputs however many there are. **But it's now giving me the first `<bullet>` of the first item on the XML file and putting it under every product, instead of showing multiple bullets for each respective product, which is what I want.**

I'll post my script and hopefully someone will be able to point out where I'm going wrong.

```
<?php
$items = simplexml_load_file('http://www.itclear.com/BestSellers.xml');

foreach ($items->channel->item as $item):
    $title=$item->title;
    $image=$item->image;
    $price=$item->price;
    $description=$item->description;
    $link=$item->link;

    echo '
             <div class="xsmall-12 medium-6 large-4 columns product">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img class="product-image" src="',$image,'"/>
                    </div>
                <h2 class="product-title"><strong>',$title,'</strong></h2>

                <ul>';

    $bullets = $items->channel->item->description;
    for($i=0;$i<=$bullets;$i++){
        echo '<li>',$bullets[$i]->bullet,'</li>';
    }

    echo'
               </ul><span class="product-price">&pound;',$price,'</span>
                <a class="product-link" href="',$link,'" target="_blank" title="Visit ITC Sales to buy ',$title,'">View Deal <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div>
         </div>';
    endforeach;
```

?>

[Rendered HTML & CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGBY5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
$bullets = $items->channel->item->description;
```

This line has no mention of the elements you're looping over in the outer `foreach` loop, so has no way to know which `item` you want to look at. It just says "look at the first `<channel>` in the document, then look at the first `<item>` in that, then look at the `<description>` elements in that".

What you want is to use the `$item` variable defined in your loop, and look at the `<description>` elements *there*:

```
$bullets = $item->description;
```

But this variable name is not quite right - the `$bullets` variable now holds one or more `<description>` elements, not the `<bullet>` elements under it. So we should instead say:

```
$description = $item->description;
$bullets = $description->bullet;
```

Note that we don't now need `$bullets[$i]->bullet`, because `$bullets[$i]` should already be the `<bullet>` element; you also need to `count()` the bullets, which is missing in your code. So we have:

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($bullets);$i++){
    echo '<li>',$bullets[$i],'</li>';
}
```

To simplify all this, you can just use the same style of `foreach` loop you already have at the top of the file:

```
foreach ( $item->description->bullet as $bullet ) {
    echo '<li>',$bullet,'</li>';
}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, this works perfectly for me, I'm sure I tried this but I must have done it differently. Thanks IMSoP

Answer (score 0):

I also found an alternative solution to this for those also stuck with a similar problem. Here's the code:

```
    <?php

        $xml = 'http://www.itclear.com/BestSellers.xml';

        $items = simplexml_load_file($xml);

        foreach ($items->channel->item as $item) {

            $title = $item->title;
            $image=$item->image;
            $price=$item->price;
            $description=$item->description;
            $link=$item->link;

            echo '
             <div class="xsmall-12 medium-6 large-4 columns product">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img class="product-image" src="',$image,'"/>
                    </div>
                <h2 class="product-title"><strong>',$title,'</strong></h2>

                <ul class="product-description">';

            foreach ($item->description->bullet as $bullet) {
                echo '<li>';
                $b = $bullet;
                echo $b;
                echo "</li>";

            }


            echo'
               </ul><span class="product-price">&pound;',$price,'</span>
                <a class="product-link" href="',$link,'" target="_blank" title="Visit ITC Sales to buy ',$title,'">View Deal <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div>
         </div>';

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: This isn't an "alternative" solution, it is exactly what I wrote at the end of my answer. (Except that here you're creating a variable `$b` with exactly the same value as `$bullet` for absolutely no reason.)